# Suggest endpoint in the Search REST service in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, search, search-api

I was trying to build a search box with suggestions as user typing
using this endpoint "/_api/search/suggest" documentation in 
[SharePoint Search REST API overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview).

However it doesn't seems work for me, does anyone came across this and know what  might went wrong for me? Thanks for help.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to see if you actually have any query suggestions for the term in question. There is a process that creates the query suggestions and stores them in the Search Service Application. You can use PowerShell to find the Suggestions that you have:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$owner = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchOwner -Level Ssa
$manager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Query.FederationManager –ArgumentList $ssa
$source = $manager.GetSourceByName("Local SharePoint Results", $owner)

Get-SPEnterpriseSearchLanguageResourcePhrase -SearchApplication $ssa `
-Owner $owner -Language en-US -Type QuerySuggestionAlwaysSuggest
```

If you find that you don't have any phrases you can add them manually with:

```
New-SPEnterpriseSearchLanguageResourcePhrase
```

Once you know that is all working your REST request should be (for example "SharePoint":

```
_api/search/suggest?querytext='SharePoint'&fprequerysuggestions=true
```